# How would I run a php script when my server receives an email

Tags: php, email

I am trying to build a website that would receive emails at addresses like bob@domainame.com
I would like to run a php script every single time the server receives an email. How would I do that?

thanks in advance!! =)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `procmail`, and execute the command-line PHP if a mail arrives or download the page with `curl` or `wget`.

Answer (score 0):

Make a script that checks if there are new mails and then run the script you need. The script that checks for new mails should be run by cron.

Comment: Is that very efficient? How often should I have the cron job run? This definitely works, but I don't think it is ideal

Comment: @bzupnick: Its the only way i know. The period depends on you need. My mailtracker is running every 5 minutes.